# Answering questions that show lack of research?

Tags: discussion, answers, etiquette, question-quality

There is always a discussion open regarding homework questions, duplicates, etc. But I can't seem to find anything that tackles a few questions I have.

I have just come across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23781507/mysql-connecting-three-tables-and-sum) ([<10k screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ud6vk.png)) question that shows an obvious lack of research. For this reason, (to me) it can fall under the "homework" question category.

When looking through SO I found similar questions (not exact) but ones where if you picked the pieces out you would put the answer together. *I linked one of these into the comments and this seemed to be the solution.*

Later, I noticed someone answered the question by giving them the code.

**A few questions arose from this, that I looked around meta for but was unable to find a clear answer to.**

---

1. Should I have flagged this as duplicate?
2. Should I have posted the link as an answer notifying the poster of their lack of research and provide them with resources and information on how SO works?
3. Should the answer by someone else have recieved a down vote? He was spoon-feeding, should this be discouraged?

---

Is there somewhere where these are clearly laid out and I'm just missing it? (If so, sorry) but then why was it so hard to find?

I'm throwing a lot of questions around, but I'd appreciate if someone would shed some light.

Comment: The person hasn't done a simple google search = lack of research, the person hasn't done an SO search =  lack of research.

Comment: It's quite obvious they haven't if you search for it yourself and find a solution. Nevertheless, there is no need to be so technical around this sentence- what does it matter if you use a quantitative measure or common sense for something like this?

Comment: I would have closed as "too broad", but [a recent discussion about "algorithms"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255590/another-invalid-failed-audit) has made me question this. Now I find myself looking for the thin line between valid algorithm & too broad.

Comment: What about questions where the user just dumps a whole lot of code and says "it doesn't work" and something along the lines of "I got this code from somewhere, I don't actually understand this programming language at all." Is this considered lack of research?

Comment: I'm grateful for the question. There are behaviors that seem difficult to discourage.  Some questions, you can't help but dislike, but the alternatives aren't completely satisfying. You hope nobody answers, but you're not quite into a downvote. Sometimes, you just want to decorate the question with garland or something - maybe flag it with "Really?" and cause a halving of the scores for accepted and upvoted answers :-)

Comment: @light: Also "too broad", because for an answer to be useful to the person asking, it would have to contain an entire course teaching the programming language.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

First, let me note that something merely being homework is not a reason to close. Very good questions can be asked from homework. *But*, the question still has to meet our quality standards.

1. Voting as a duplicate can be a *little* tricky at times, and it's one of the few 'moderation' duties that often requires domain knowledge. (Hence the recent feature where Gold badge users of a tag can single-handedly close as duplicate). That there is an answer there which *perfectly* answers the newer question can be a strong indicator, but you should also be sure the question's root problem is the same one. Those questions seem pretty close, but I can't say absolutely one way or another if I would vote to close the same, so I wouldn't. But you may know more than I do there.
2. Do not post a mere link as an answer, no. You can post a link as a comment - and ask if they feel it's a duplicate. Also, if you feel it really is a duplicate, and an answer there handles it well, it's probably best to reconsider posting an answer at all. You should probably avoid even a detailed answer that's simply a restatement of one of the answers on the original, IMHO.
3. I don't like spoon-feeding. Many others agree. Many others don't. Why you down vote is your own business, as long as it's not for revenge or cheating. I know there are people who down vote for this. The idea behind it is that it's "Not Useful", as the down vote tooltip says. An argument can definitely be made for that.

Your questions here are not new; many people wrestle with this, so don't feel alone. In the end, do what you feel is 'proper'; just do it objectively based on the content.

Comment: This was quite helpful, thanks. In this occasion where the link I posted in the comments seems to have solved his problem, should I have marked as duplicate? The root problem has a slight variation, but it's not big enough that someone with the slightest knowledge in the field couldn't figure it out.

Comment: If you've gotten confirmation from the asker that the answers there solved their problem, that is definitely a strong indicator of a duplicate, yes. @CoderDojo

Comment: Thanks :) I admire how you've considered both opinions with regards to spoon-feeding.

Answer (score 10):

First of all, let's remember that the goal of SO <strike>[is somewhat unclear at the moment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254770/what-is-stack-overflows-goal)</strike> is to create and provide a usable reference for common programming problems. It is not a discussion forum, a free personal help service or any other such thing. The effort put into every question asked and answered should help more than just the one individual person that asked the question, it should stand as a reference to other people in the future who encounter the same problem. As such...

> Should I have flagged this as duplicate?

If there is a clear duplicate, or an existing answer which if read and understood should clarify things for the OP in a way that his question becomes answered, then it should absolutely be flagged as a duplicate. We do not need to have the same issue answered in a thousand different ways with varying quality every time. This makes SO less usable as a general references, because it devolves into a personalised help forum instead of a generalised reference. Programmers using this reference are expected to make a bit of a jump from A to B to apply generalised solutions we provide here to their individual code, we do not want to handwrite code for each and everyone individually here.

> Should I have posted the link as an answer notifying the poster of their lack of research and provide them with resources and information on how SO works?

You should certainly not post links as an answer, no. Close as duplicate, done. You also don't need to harp on the fact that the OP lacked research effort, but you should politely point that out in a comment. Hopefully he'll get the drift after a while.

> Should the answer by someone else have recieved a down vote? He was spoon-feeding, should this be discouraged?

I don't think punishing users who *do* put effort into the system (as opposed to OPs who do not) is of any use. Unless the answer is blatantly wrong or deals out bad advice, there's no reason to downvote it. Perhaps the answerer *has* tried to look for a duplicate but couldn't find one that was very useful in the sea of answers out there (happens a lot). That probably means there *is* no useful duplicate, or that it's so obscure that no one can find it with the given keywords. In this case adding an answer is useful for everyone. If the question does get closed as a duplicate later, so be it. The system didn't get any worse from it.

Vote on questions based on whether they add any new useful knowledge to the system by covering new, interesting, generally useful ground or at least whether they're well formed. Vote on answers based on their correctness and whether there's anything useful to learn from them. Close questions as duplicates when it's clear that they are one. Leave meta commentary such as etiquette and effort-related comments in the comments.

Comment: Despite what might seem like minor differences between our answers, I like this one a lot, too. And maybe the quote/response method would have been a more readable way to respond to the questions!