# How should we treat answers to questions that show no effort?

Tags: discussion, answers, low-quality-posts

I was looking around on meta to see the community's stance on answering homework questions when I came across [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255657/answering-questions-that-show-lack-of-research).

While it does seem to confirm my views on the issue, it does open a new question: How should we treat answers that simply provide code to a question which shows absolutely no effort, like a classic homework dump?

I feel that these answers, while technically providing a solution to the asker's problem, end up likely doing more harm than good in the long run, both to the asker and potentially SO.

If it is simply a code dump solution without explanation, then it is unlikely that the asker will actually learn anything, as they are probably simply going to copy and paste the code, see that it works and forget all about it. Of course this would be a low quality answer in general, but I would consider it especially harmful in this situation.

I also feel that it causes two issues for SO as a whole:

1. It allows people to "snipe reputation" by looking for easy homework problems and simply dumping their answer there. Of course, this is not really a problem if the answer actually explains things well and is of high quality, but I am talking specifically about code dumps here.
2. It only encourages more of these questions, and I think there is already an excessive amount of them.

So what should we do? Should we downvote answers like that? Should we simply leave a comment stating that answering these sorts of questions can be problematic? Or should we simply ignore the possible issue and treat them like any other answer? What is the community's stance on this?

Comment: See also e.g. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255853/should-downvotes-be-used-to-punish-people-who-answer-bad-questions