# Was I wrong to answer question which showed no research effort?

Tags: discussion, answers, downvotes, bad-questions

Today I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41035031/how-to-convert-varchar-in-24hours-time-sql-server/) which already had a downvote and a comment from a high-rep user prompting the asker to explain what they'd already tried and what exactly they were stuck on (a comment which I voted for).

Without really thinking, I went ahead and answered the question (as it was straightforward to do so and I like to help, that's why I'm here!), but I then wondered if instead I should have done something different?

If I hadn't known the answer to this question, I would definitely have downvoted it on the basis of not showing any research effort (although it was clear and arguably a useful question), but for some reason I felt a little conflicted in simultaneously downvoting and answering a question.

Is there a clear "best practice" I should have followed when I encountered this question, or is it more of a judgement call on a case-by-case basis? I have found other questions on SO Meta which deal with whether to answer bad questions or not, but none with answers specifically about answering questions which lack evidence of research effort.

**Edit:**

I already found and read the question which has now been flagged as a possible duplicate ([Answering questions that show lack of research?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255657/answering-questions-that-show-lack-of-research)), but don't feel that the answers given there answer my question here. That question asks:

- **Should I have flagged as duplicate?**

I could not find any other question with an answer which clearly addressed this question in a way that I felt the OP would understand and be able to use.

- **Should I have posted a link to some resource as an answer?**

As above, I did not have anything which I felt was a relevant resource to link to.

- **Should I have downvoted a given answer?**

I am not asking about downvoting answers to bad questions, but rather whether or not to answer them (and if so, how).

None of these points are my question, which is: should I have answered this question (and should I answer others like it)? If yes, should I have answered differently and if no, should I have done anything instead of answering?

**Edit 2:**

Seems this question has been closed as a duplicate even after my edit above explaining why I don't think it's a duplicate. Guess I'm not going to get a clear answer (perhaps because there isn't one)?

Comment: If the question is bad, I guess answering and downvoting is better than answering without downvoting

Comment: From @deceze in the duplicate: *Perhaps the answerer has tried to look for a duplicate but couldn't find one that was very useful in the sea of answers out there (happens a lot). That probably means there is no useful duplicate, or that it's so obscure that no one can find it with the given keywords. In this case adding an answer is useful for everyone.*

Comment: It is sort of okay, the [sql] and [regex] tags fall in a special category.  Google very rarely helps to find an existing answer, nobody expects a programmer to master the details and SO users just love to outsource the programming job.  They get served too, some contributors dust-off these kind of questions at a very high rate, earn a lot of rep doing so.  Marc is showing clear signs of what eventually happens to such contributors, it does wear anybody down.  He lasted a lot longer than I would have.

Comment: This might provide the answer that you're looking for: [Does it violate Stack Overflow rules to answer a narrow and specific “give me teh codez” question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269244/does-it-violate-stack-overflow-rules-to-answer-a-narrow-and-specific-give-me-te)

Comment: @MichaelGaskill yes, that is much closer to what I am asking and I would be fairly happy to consider my question a duplicate of that, thanks!

Comment: [This](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/338846/4639281) is more specifically about non-debugging questions that do not contain code, but the principle applies. Is the question on-topic and answerable in its current state? Every post on stack overflow *could* be improved. Questions don't need to be perfect to be answerable. If it is lacking enough detail to answer, dont just guess. If it is a debugging style question, it must include an mcve, example input, expected output, actual outout, and any errors that were encountered.