# When, if ever, will I stop getting review audits?

Tags: discussion, support, review-queues, review-audits

When I crossed reputation to 3k+ I get privileged to mark posts as off-topic or duplicate.

[image]

I'm always doing using my privileges to help community to decide whether a post is off-topic or duplicate. Everyday I get 50 flags to mark. While doing it, I got this:

[image]

Firstly I wondered about it, but was happy that, I passed in community test. But then I get to know that this check is made every time. Ok, still I feel good that I'm doing what our community wants.

But then I asked meself a few questions:

- How long will this test be performed on me?
- Is it only for me or for each reviewer?
- If a reviewer passed in every tests then, any chance that he'll not test again?
- When and why this test will perform on a reviewer (specific conditions)?
- If a moderator or "trusted user" will do reviewing, he'll also need to pass through that test?

Comment: I hope never...

Comment: If it makes you feel any better I still get review audits too. Sometimes I blow one and get the "PAY ATTENTION!" warning. <shrug> Life goes on...

Comment: I got one of those yesterday.

Comment: The "paying attention" part has more to do with it then "trusted user" or "mad review skillz" (ok that one is me).  That is why they persist.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

If you review, you will **always** be served audits from time to time.

If you do well enough on these audits, you'll be served fewer *but you will still be served them from time to time*. The audits are served at random, the only thing that changes is the ratio at which they are served (see the [original suggestion for details](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/183017), in effect since [May 2014](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/231181)).

Trusted users and diamond moderators are not exempt from audits.

Comment: What happens if you fail one of these audits?

Comment: @StuartMarks: that depends on how many audits you have failed in the past 30 days. Hit a threshold percentage and you get temporarily banned from reviewing (starting at 1 day, then 7, then 30, for repeat offenders).

Comment: @StuartMarks Failing a hard one here and there won't do much, but you will get review banned if you fail too many (the exact conditions aren't publicly known, as far as I know).

Comment: @Dukeling: It's a threshold percentage covering all audits given to you in the past 30 days, but what percentage that is is not public knowledge.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Are you sure it's over a 30 day period? Meaning you get treated the same regardless of whether you fail every audit you get, or you do `1200-x` good reviews, with `x` failed audits. That doesn't make too much sense to me, but I suppose it's possible that it works that way.

Comment: @Dukeling: see [The time of automatic review bans should be increased with every new ban](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/190562) and  [Failed review ban - 30 day window - clarification please](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/199789)

Comment: @Dukeling: There are more Meta.SE posts that discuss bans; where someone feels they have been banned unfairly and it's pointed out that it's a percentage. I am having trouble finding a good example atm.

Comment: @MartijnPieters That's bans though, not the actual failed audits - the second link might be otherwise accurate, but implying that you get banned after one audit definitely isn't, at least not on the close vote queue.

Comment: Could you clarify the chance of getting an audit to "a 5% chance of being served an audit per review after 5 reviews"?  I had to follow the link to understand which you meant.

Comment: @mydogisbox: I'm not going to overcomplicate my answer though; it is not that relevant in the context of the question. There is a fixed percentage, the chances don't increase or decrease with how many audits you passed or failed or how much reputation or badges you have.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Based on this [answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/231181/193563) it would seem that the ratio of review audits is not the same for everyone but is adjusted based on your review history.

Comment: @Jack: I initially wrote my answer based on Shog's suggestion already being implemented, then couldn't find the evidence that it had, so I altered my answer. Thanks for finding the evidence, now I can revert. :-)

Comment: @Jack: ironically enough, the post you found was just a short scroll away, not sure how I missed that.

Comment: As I get maybe every second day a test, I stop reviewing for at least that day

Comment: I have never failed a review audit but I still get them every single time I do reviews.  It's annoying... if they actually decreased in frequency that would be really great.

Answer (score 20):

If the review audit goes away, that just invites lazy reviews. This keeps you sharp and on your toes!

Comment: Not really.  After about six of them, they are easy to spot.  Also, in some cases, the audit picks [dumb questions](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255590/another-invalid-failed-audit).  The audit should be a review of the review.  If we present the same review 20 times and 20 people fail, then probably it is closed for a poor reason.  Also, the review audit automatically inserts filtered tags, which can kind of change the meaning of the review.  Some high point questions could be considered *off-topic*.  The reviews would be better with a corpus and used as a double check.

Answer (score 4):

Reviewing requires skills, if you have enough rep for review posts doesn't mean you have enough skills to do it seamlessly. You have to learn much to make a review work powerful to you and probably other reviewers on the chain. Audits is like a self-check your skills to provide a help by reviewing post. Actually it's a moderator job and you as moderator doing it. The main purpose of the tests is to unmask a robo-reviewer, so it will work always regardless of account and rep on it. You can't know when a test will be as well as if is a test a current review, otherwise tests make no sense. You can learn on tests if you fail trying to understand why you didn't pass. If you get only "Congratulations!" than I glad for you, you are a great reviewer.