# Strange Happening in First Posts Review Queue

Tags: discussion, review-audits

So I thought I'd help out a little and review a few posts in the First Posts queue, since there were 21 posts by "new users" that had to be reviewed. (And yes, I put the quotes there for a reason.) The first post I decided to skip since I wasn't certain about the action I should have taken. I examined the second post, seeing the surprisingly well-written answer that the user wrote, and clicked the "No Action Needed" button.

After I clicked the button, something strange occurred. The answer changed, showing 11 votes instead of 1 previously, a green checkmark to the side, the date showing that it was posted three days ago, and the following message displayed above it:

> [image]

So the system threw me for a loop by disguising a high-quality post, making it seem like it was created by a new user. My reactions were to be utterly surprised and even a little creeped out by what just happened.

Does this always occur with everyone, or only with reviewers who've been doing a meager job of reviewing lately? How often should I expect something like this to happen?

Comment: Audits occur in all of the review queues, because there are people who only show up and click the same button on every single review just to earn a badge (which is just plain sad). Everybody gets audits, no matter what your performance, though I believe if you have a history of review bans, you might receive *more* audits - though don't quote me on that. See also http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260154/

Comment: Ah. I didn't realize that it was just a review audit. Thanks!

Comment: @TNT Congrats! :-P ...